# Compare PS file variables(1-8) and PDS members(1-8) and create PDS members file for all matching PDS names

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl

I have a requirement to match 2 files(first file is PS file and second file is a PDS file)

PS file 1-8 bytes are member names:
Example:

```
ABCD1234
DDFF2345
QWER3456
```

PDS file has 100 members and above given 3 members are matching.
Example:

```
AAAA1234
ABCD1234
DDFF2345
QWER3456
SSSS2222
HHHH1212
```

My requirement is to create output PDS file with those 3 matching members(Same as of input PDS file)
Result PDS file:

```
ABCD1234
DDFF2345
QWER3456
```

If anyone can please guide or give an idea would be very helpful.

Regards
Harry

Answer (score 0):

Write a step to obtain the list of members in the PDS.  There are various ways to do this, in-house utilities, third-party utilities, write your own clist or Rexx wrapping the LISTDS TSO command.  Use whatever method is commonly in use in your shop.  If you don't know what's commonly in use in your shop, ask your coworkers.  Save the output in a file.

Write a step to execute your shop's SORT utility to match-merge the list of members from the first step with the list in the PS file.  Both DFSORT and Syncsort can do this, see the JOINFILE keyword in the documentation.  Save the list of members that match in a file.

Here's the tricky part: write a step to read the list of members from the match-merge step and output IEBCOPY control statements to copy the members.  If you want to get fancy, you could combine this step with the previous step.

Write a step to execute IEBCOPY to execute the control statements written by the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to USS you can do what you want by following this example:

The example uses the following dataset names, but you can replace
them with the actual dataset names in your case:

PS:  `hlq.MEMBER.LIST`     <--- the list of members you want

PDS: `hlq.PDS.DATASET`     <--- the PDS dataset with members you wan to copy

PDS: `hlq.NEWPDS.DATASET`  <--- the PDS dataset to which you want to copy the members

Create the list of members from `hlq.PDS.DATASET` into a USS file `pds.members`

```
> tsocmd "listds 'hlq.PDS.DATASET' MEMBERS" >pds.members
```

Copy each member listed in `hlq.MEMBER.LIST` that is in `hlq.PDS.DATASET` into the `hlq.NEWPDS.DATASET`

```
> for fn in $(cat "//'hlq.MEMBER.LIST'"); do grep $fn pds.members >/dev/null 2>&1; [ $? -eq 0 ] && cp "//'hlq.PDS.DATASET($fn)'" "//'hlq.NEWPDS.DATASET'";  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an edit macro to turn that list of members into IEBCOPY control statements to copy the members:

```
COPY INDD=INLIB,OUTDD=OUTLIB  
SELECT MEMBER=(ABCD1234)
SELECT MEMBER=(DDFF2345)
SELECT MEMBER=(QWER3456)
```

and then use this edited data as input to an IEBCOPY job to copy those members to a new PDS:

```
//COPY     EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                
//*                                                     
//INLIB     DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=<old.pds>                   
//OUTLIB    DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=<new.pds>                        
//*                                                     
//SYSUT3   DD   UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(50,50))          
//SYSUT4   DD   UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(50,50))          
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*                                
//SYSIN    DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=<new.control.statements>
```